# how can i make a json file to a dictionary?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm beginner with python. My json file is:

```
{
    "dog": {
        "dog1": ["cat1", "cat2"],
        "dog2": ["cat2", "cat1"]
    },
    "cat": {
        "cat1": ["dog1", "dog2"],
        "cat2": ["dog1", "dog2"]
    }
}
```

I saved the json file to a variable x :

```
import json

f = open(jsonfile, 'r')
x = json.load(f)
f.close()
```

Now i want to make 2 dictionaries with names "cat" and "dog". How can i do it? P.s the file json can be different everytime a person calls the programm. Especially, it can has more or less dogs or cats.

Answer (score 2):

```
import json

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    animals = json.load(f)

dog_dict = animals['dog']
cat_dict = animals['cat']
```

Comment: if I want to make a dictionary like:

dog_status = { 'dog1': 'Homeless', 'dog2' : 'Homeless' }

What should i do?

Comment: Either you simply have to change the JSON file itself, and keep the same code, or I don't understand your second question.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a dictionary with your json code that was converted to a python dicationary `json.load(f)`. In your json are more dictinoaries. There is nothing special to it just assign them to a new variable if you want to.

```
dog_dict = x['dog']
```

Comment: if I want to make a dictionary like:

dog_status = { 'dog1': 'Homeless', 'dog2' : 'Homeless' }

What should i do?